# does external content in an iframe count as a page hit for the external provider?

Tags: iframe, web

Simple question really - does content from an external site rendered in an iframe count as a page hit for the external content provider?

If my page www.mysite.com/iframepage has an iframe loading content from www.yoursite/yourpage would views on my page count as traffic to both sites?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Whatever happens inside the iframe is as if you had opened the page in a normal browser window.